# The permission is not granted from HUAWEI Developers. But i do not know how to solve it according to this message only

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, appgallery, appgallery-connect

After my game integrated the HMS Core SDK, players could not sign in to my game.
When the getCurrentPlayer API was called,
result code 6004 was returned.
I searched the keyword hmssdk in log information and found the following error
information:Line 291: I/HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code6004, api_name:game.getCurrentPlayer
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is a typical one many developers encountered, please do the following:

•   The resulting code indicates that the required permission has not been granted, please refer to [Enabling Services](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References-V5/error-code-0000001050045846-V5). Also If the required API is not enabled, after enable it, you need to wait for about 15 minutes, clear the HMS Core (APK) cache on the test phone, and check whether sign-in can be successful.
[image]

•    If the API has been enabled, the possible cause is that an exception occurs when the API is enabled, which rarely happens. As a result, Huawei server does not receive the synchronized API enabling request. In this case, you can manually disable the API and then enable it again to trigger message synchronization. Similarly, clear the HMS Core (APK) cache, wait for 15 minutes, and perform the test again.

•   To clear the HMS Core (APK) cache, go to Settings > Apps > Apps > HMS Core on your test device, and clear the cache.